# Copy one row to another column in same table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

There's the table where `CUSTOMERS` that are recognized by unique `ID` values, all records in this table also have `CONSENT` boolean attributes.

I need to copy those `CONSENT` values to `CONSENT2` boolean fields for the same records.

As far as I know, there are several SQL commands that are disabled on this server.

Would this work?

```
UPDATE
    CUSTOMERS
SET
    CUSTOMERS_A.CONSENT_Email = CUSTOMERS_A.CONSENT_Email2
    CUSTOMERS_A.CONSENT_Phone = CUSTOMERS_A.CONSENT_Phone2
FROM
    CUSTOMERS AS CUSTOMERS_A
    INNER JOIN CUSTOMERS AS CUSTOMERS_B
        ON CUSTOMERS_A.id = CUSTOMERS_B.id
```

Comment: You want to copy from "CONSENT" to "CONSENT2", like, from CONSENT_Email will be copied to CONSENT_Email2, is it? or opposite?

Comment: That is correct, from CONSENT_Email to CONSENT_Email2

Comment: I have posted an answer try that, and let us know if there is any issue!

Comment: I will run some tests now, thank you for the help

Answer (score 1):

You can do without join

```
UPDATE
CUSTOMERS
   SET CONSENT_Email = CONSENT_Email2,
       CONSENT_Phone = CONSENT_Phone2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use, Don't add extra join/condition until really that required.

```
UPDATE CUSTOMERS
   SET (CONSENT_Email2,CONSENT_Phone2) = (CONSENT_Email,CONSENT_Phone);
```

It will copy the CONSENT2 values for both of columns into CONSENT.

```
i.e. CONSENT >>> CONSENT2
```

Comment: It appears that the query must start with SELECT statement. Would it require adjusting this query a lot?